# How to know whats beneath my finger

Tags: android, android-layout, events, touch

I have different elements on the XML file like Buttons,TextView etc. Is there a way in which the phone will speak the element on which the finger touches.

Suppose if the Button is touched, it says it's name and when you slide to next adjacent item it automatically says the new name. I have tried using `ACTION_MOVE` events, but its like you have to set the property for each element.

Is there a way you can set this for whole layout and when you move or touch the layout it identifies whats beneath the touched area and returns some sort of ID.

Answer (score 0):

How about set your layout in weight

> android:weight="1"

And get the width and height

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

When ACTION_MOVE get the X,Y

For example,

```
if(x < width/2 && y < height/3)
    return item.getID();
```

[image]

I know it is not a smart way, just a quick way

Comment: yes definitely thats a way to do but as you said not the smart one...... I hope there is someone who knows the Smart Way :)

Comment: or add onClick on every items that return ID

Comment: adding onClick wont help on "moving" from item to item. Even ACTION_MOVE didn't helped.